# Blockhound exception occurs even with explicit schedulers

Tags: reactive-programming, spring-webflux, project-reactor, blockhound

I have a similar snippet of code to scheduler an I/O on separate thread pool but unfortunately, we do need its response to decide to proceed further or not.

```
private Response getItemsNonBlockingMethod(String id, final String path) {
        WebTarget webTarget = sampleServWebTarget
                .path(path).queryParam("id", id);
        Mono<Response> responseMono = Mono.fromCallable(() -> {
            // Blocking I/O is scheduled on a separate thread pool
            return webTarget.request().get();
        }).subscribeOn(Schedulers.boundedElastic());
        return responseMono.block()
    }
```

I have enabled blockhound on my local, this seems to be working fine for most of the cases. But when I do Load and Performance testing, I do see like ~10 occurences of blockhound exception, Am I missing something ? Are there any better way to block in spring reactor version 3.4 ?

Update:

Stack Trace:

```
reactor.blockhound.BlockingOperationError: Blocking call! sun.misc.Unsafe#park
    at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Unsafe.java)
    Suppressed: reactor.core.publisher.FluxOnAssembly$OnAssemblyException: 
Assembly trace from producer [reactor.core.publisher.MonoError] :
    reactor.core.publisher.Mono.error
    reactor.netty.http.client.HttpClientConnect$HttpClientHandler.requestWithBody(HttpClientConnect.java:559)
Error has been observed at the following site(s):
    |_      Mono.error ⇢ at reactor.netty.http.client.HttpClientConnect$HttpClientHandler.requestWithBody(HttpClientConnect.java:559)
    |_ Mono.fromDirect ⇢ at reactor.netty.http.client.HttpClientConnect$HttpIOHandlerObserver.lambda$onStateChange$0(HttpClientConnect.java:398)
    |_      Mono.defer ⇢ at reactor.netty.http.client.HttpClientConnect$HttpIOHandlerObserver.onStateChange(HttpClientConnect.java:398)
```

Comment: If it is a webflux application you should not block at all. What is the error you get from BlockHound?

Comment: we use JAX-RS with AsyncResponse pattern. Error we get is reactor.blockhound.BlockingOperationError: Blocking call!  sun.misc.unsafe.park